# How do I intercept a paste event in an editbox?

Tags: c, winapi, edit-control

How do I intercept a paste event in an editbox, possibly before the value is transferred to the object?

Answer (score 1):

Look up [subclassing windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997565.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass then intercept the WM_PASTE message you can do what you want, throw the message away to prevent the paste, manipulate the clipboard data, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the edit box and handle the WM_PASTE message.