# How to disable copy/paste in TEdit

Tags: clipboard, c++builder, vcl

I would like to prevent copy, cut and paste in my `TEdit`. How can I do this?

I tried setting the `Key=NULL` on `KeyDown` event when <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> was pressed on the control, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try the OnKeyUp event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158861/how-to-intercept-detect-a-paste-command-into-a-tmemo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to prevent the `WM_CUT`, `WM_COPY`, and `WM_PASTE` messages from being sent to your TEdit.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96271/how-do-i-intercept-a-paste-event-in-an-editbox) describes how do to this using just the Windows API.  For the VCL, it may be sufficient to subclass `TEdit` and change its `DefWndProc` property or override its `WndProc` method.

Answer (score 5):

Assign this to `TEdit.OnKeyPress` :

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
 if (Key=#22) or (Key=#3) then Key:=#0;   // 22 = [Ctrl+V] / 3 = [Ctrl+C]
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the user clicks the right mouse button and selects Paste.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I'll add what I have found.  The original poster almost had the solution.  It works fine if you ignore cut/copy/paste in the key press event instead of the key down event.  ie (c++ builder)

```
void __fastcall Form::OnKeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
   if( Key==0x03/*ctrl-c*/ || Key==0x16/*ctrl-v*/ || Key==0x018/*ctrl-x*/ )
      Key = 0;  //ignore key press
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some global programs that grab shortcuts and block C-V C-C C-X when TEdit window is active

Answer (score 0):

```
Uses Clipbrd;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Clipboard.AsText := '';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but the same bad answers are still floating around.

```
unit LockEdit;

// Version of TEdit with a property CBLocked that prevents copying, pasting,
// and cutting when the property is set.

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, StdCtrls, Windows;

type

  TLockEdit = class(TEdit)
  protected
      procedure WndProc(var msg: TMessage); override;
  private
      FLocked: boolean;
  public
      property CBLocked: boolean read FLocked write FLocked default false;
  end;

implementation

  procedure TLockEdit.WndProc(Var msg: TMessage);
  begin
  if ((msg.msg = WM_PASTE) or (msg.msg = WM_COPY) or (msg.msg = WM_CUT))
      and CBLocked
          then msg.msg:=WM_NULL;
  inherited;
  end;

end.
```