# How to intercept (detect) a Paste command into a TMemo?

Tags: delphi, detect, paste, intercept, memo

How to catch Paste command and change text of Clipboard before that text is pasted into a `TMemo`, but, after Paste, text in Clipboard must be same like before changing?

Example,  Clipboard have text `'Simple Question'`, text that go in the `TMemo` is `'Симплe Qуeстиoн'`, and after that text in Clipboard is like before changing, `'Simple Question'`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Derive a new control that descends from 'TMemo' to intercept the `WM_PASTE` message:

```
type
  TPastelessMemo = class(TMemo)
  protected
    procedure WMPaste(var Message: TWMPaste); message WM_PASTE;
  end;

uses
  clipbrd;

procedure TPastelessMemo.WMPaste(var Message: TWMPaste);
var
  SaveClipboard: string;
begin
  SaveClipboard := Clipboard.AsText;
  Clipboard.AsText := 'Simple Question';
  inherited;
  Clipboard.AsText := SaveClipboard;
end;
```

If you would like to prohibit any paste operation at all, empty the WMPaste handler.

Comment: :) I think you've nailed it. +1, and removing my comments.

Answer (score 7):

This is an alternative to Sertac's excellent answer, which is to override the control's WndProc:

```
// For detecting WM_PASTE messages on the control
OriginalMemoWindowProc: TWndMethod;
procedure NewMemoWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
//...

// In the form's OnCreate procedure:
// Hijack the control's WindowProc in order to detect WM_PASTE messages
OriginalMemoWindowProc := myMemo.WindowProc;
myMemo.WindowProc := NewMemoWindowProc;
//...

procedure TfrmMyForm.NewMemoWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
    bProcessMessage: Boolean;
begin
    bProcessMessage := True;
    if (Message.Msg = WM_PASTE) then
        begin
        // Data pasted into the memo!
        if (SomeCondition) then
            bProcessMessage := False;   // Do not process this message any further!
        end;

    if (bProcessMessage) then
        begin
        // Ensure all (valid) messages are handled!
        OriginalMemoWindowProc(Message);
        end;
end;
```