# How are Ctrl + Key shortcuts translated in the OnKeyPress event?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, delphi-2007

I was trying to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> from a `TEdit`'s `OnKeyPress` event and I've noticed that the `Key` parameter assumes an unusual value when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AnyKey</kbd>.

**Example:**

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Ord(Key)));
end;
```

It produces the following results:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> 17
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> 23
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> 5
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> 18
- ...
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> 1
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> 26
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> 3
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> 22
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> 24

I don't understand how keys are translated, what does these codes mean?

It seems it has nothing to do with the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/):

[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: This sounds like the wrong solution. Shouldn't you listen for WM_PASTE. Then program will work with users that paste user other methods. Like the context menu. Or Ctrl+Insert.

Comment: And if you ever did need to catch Ctrl+key presses then OnKeyPress is the wrong way to do it. So it looks very much like this question has been asked with two incorrect premises.

Comment: You are getting the [ascii control character](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/c0.html) values.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: My initial goal was that to set `Key` parameter to `#0` if `Clipboard.AsText` doesn't contain only number characters but maybe I'll ask another question about that. I've created this question because I'm curious about the way keys are translated into chars for the `OnKeyPress` event

Comment: This could be helpful: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447

Comment: This is of academic interest then, and @LURD tells you what is going on. But it won't be of any use solving your problem as I outlined. I don't think you need to ask a new for that though. I think I already told you what to do.

Comment: You can study [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10158921/576719) example, how to intercept the `WM_PASTE` message in a control.

Comment: @LURD: Thanks, your comments have been very helpful

Comment: @LURD: Your first comment answers to my question, if you post it with a little explanation I'll be glad to accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't understand how keys are translated, what does these codes mean?

The values you get with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AnyKey</kbd> combinations are Ascii control codes.
They emanate from the need to enter non-printing (control) characters from the keyboard. The (typical) values for the control characters are below 32 plus the `del` character (127).

[image]

Some more information about the history behind and standards could be found [here](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/c0.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).