# How to intercept and suppress a message for a TFrame's subcomponent?

Tags: delphi, paste, delphi-2007, windows-messages

I need to [intercept the `WM_PASTE` message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158861/how-to-intercept-detect-a-paste-command-into-a-tmemo/10158921#10158921) for a `TEdit` component which is placed inside a `TFrame`'s descendant class.

If a condition is not satisfied, I want to iniby the paste operation.

Is there a way to do this at the frame level? (I mean, without declaring a `TEdit`'s descendant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this at the frame level? (I mean, without declaring a `TEdit`'s descendant)

`WM_PASTE` is sent directly to the `TEdit` window, the `TFrame` never sees it, so you must subclass the `TEdit` directly in order to intercept the message.  You can either:

- have the `TFrame` assign a handler to the `TEdit`'s `WindowProc` property.  This is a simple approach if you have only a few `TEdit`s to subclass, but it gets more complicated the more `TEdit`s you want to subclass:

  ```
  type
    TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
      Edit1: TEdit;
      ...
      procedure FrameCreate(Sender: TObject);
      ...
    private
      PrevWndProc: TWndMethod;
      procedure EditWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
      ...
    end;

  procedure TMyFrame.FrameCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    PrevWndProc := Edit1.WindowProc;
    Edit1.WindowProc := EditWndProc;
    ...
  end;

  procedure TMyFrame.EditWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  begin
    if Message.Msg = WM_PASTE then
    begin
      if SomeCondition then
        Exit;
    end;
    PrevWndProc(Message);
  end;
  ```
- write and install a new component that is derived from `TEdit`, similar to the [`TMemo` example you presented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10158921/65863).
- define an interposer class that is local to just the `TFrame`'s unit, above the `TFrame` class declaration, which will intercept `WM_PASTE` for *every* `TEdit` on the Frame:

  ```
  type
    TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
      procedure WMPaste(var Message: TMessage); message WM_PASTE;
    end;

    TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
      Edit1: TEdit;
      Edit2: TEdit;
      ...
    end;

  procedure TEdit.WMPaste(var Message: TMessage);
  begin
    if not SomeCondition then
      inherited;
  end;
  ```

Comment: Great answer! The first way fits better for me in my case, because my frame contains other `TEdit` controls. Tested and working, thank you!